# Getting <nil> while using .Predict() function in golearn

Tags: go, machine-learning

I'm playing around with the knnclassifier_iris.go example in the golearn examples folder. I replaced the iris dataset with one of my own, and as long as I train my data on some percentage of the data I read in, all functions work fine and I get some output. However, when I clearly mention a training and testing dataset, and then run predict on the test dataset after fitting the training dataset, I get a nil result when I try to print the predictions. I don't know why I'm getting a nil value, so I would really appreciate some help.

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/base"
    "github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/evaluation"
    "github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/knn"
)

func main() {
    trainData, err := base.ParseCSVToInstances("~/Desktop/churn_train.csv", true)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(trainData)
    testData, err := base.ParseCSVToInstances("~/Desktop/churn_test.csv", false)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(trainData)
    fmt.Println(testData)

    //Initialises a new KNN classifier
    cls := knn.NewKnnClassifier("euclidean", 2)
    cls.Fit(trainData)

//Calculates the Euclidean distance and returns the most popular label
    predictions := cls.Predict(testData)
    fmt.Println(predictions) //GETTING <NIL> AS OUTPUT

    // Prints precision/recall metrics
    confusionMat, err := evaluation.GetConfusionMatrix(testData, predictions)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Unable to get confusion matrix: %s", err.Error())) //ERROR CAUSED HERE DUE TO GETTING <NIL>
    }
    fmt.Println(evaluation.GetSummary(confusionMat))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Just in case anybody's stumbled across this on Google). The issue tends to arise when the second `ParseCSVToInstances` produces instances which are subtly different from the first. To ensure that this isn't the problem, use [`ParseCSVToTemplatedInstances`](https://godoc.org/github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/base#ParseCSVToTemplatedInstances), so

```
testData, err := base.ParseCSVToInstances("~/Desktop/churn_test.csv", false)
```

becomes

```
 testData, err := base.ParseCSVToTemplatedInstances("~/Desktop/churn_test.csv", false, trainData)
```